# $("#").submit with Ajax refreshing page

Tags: javascript, jquery

Not sure what is the issue as this code was working fine some time earlier, I am trying to submit my form using `Ajax` and this is my code

### Ajax Code

```
 $(function() {
 $("#login").submit(function() {
   $('#signinPane').showLoading();
 $("#loginError").hide();
 var data = $(this).serializeObject();
    $.ajax({
        'type': "POST",
         'url': "<c:url value="/shop/customer/j_spring_security_check"/>",
         'data':data,
         'success': function(result) {

         }
       });

     return false;
   });
});
```

### HTML Code

```
<form id="login" method="post" accept-charset="UTF-8">
<input id="userName" style="margin-bottom: 15px;" type="text" name="j_username" size="30" />
<input id="password" style="margin-bottom: 15px;" type="password" name="j_password" size="30" />
<button type="submit" id="login-button"></button>
</form>
```

My issue is, when I am clicking on submit button, page is getting refresh and no Ajax call is being submitted at all.
Not sure what is happening.

Comment: are you making sure $("#login").submit is what you assign?

Comment: so what changed from when it did work?

Comment: It has to do with a button with `type="submit"` being within the `form` tags. That will always submit the form. As others have said, using `e.preventDefault()` should fix your issue.

Comment: @charlietfl: strangly no change, i have already compared alll version in my SVN and seen no change .This is strange to me

Comment: must be an error being thrown. Using `preventDefault` will let you stop submittal before your code runs, thus be able to see errors. If errors thrown returning false won't happen

Comment: the problem is with the url you have given ? do you think it is the right url?

Comment: @niko: Yes URL is correct

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you need to call `preventDefault` on event object.

Returning false is okay when you're in the vanilla JS handler, and you're not.

Comment: Unfortunately this has given no results. I tried it before asking question even

Comment: You should then update your question with that information i guess !

Comment: And also, make sure you call preventDefault before doing anything (in case something breaks and it doesn't get called)

Comment: `preventDefault ` is the first line in my JS function

Comment: I just tried something similar in a jsfiddle and all went well. I'm guessing the problem is on side code. Can you reproduce it on a fiddle ?

Comment: Yes, you are somehow correct, but still facing s strange issue `$(this).serializeObject()` is giving `TypeError: $(...).serializeObject is not a function` not sure why so many issue

Comment: Thanks, that was a great help :)

Answer (score 2):

Try passing the event as a parameter and then calling `e.preventDefault()`

<kbd>**[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wSqY4/)**</kbd> <kbd>**[Documentation](http://api.jquery.com/event.preventDefault/)**</kbd>

```
$(function() {
    $("#login").submit(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $('#signinPane').showLoading();
        $("#loginError").hide();
        var data = $(this).serializeObject();
        $.ajax({
            'type': "POST",
            'url': "<c:url value="/shop/customer/j_spring_security_check"/>",
            'data':data,
            'success': function(result) {

            }
        });
    });
});
```

Answer (score 2):

use

```
event.preventDefault();


$("#login").submit(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    $('#signinPane').showLoading();
```

This will prevent default form submit characteristic.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
$("#login").submit(function(e) {
 e.preventDefault();
 e.stopPropagation();
```

http://api.jquery.com/event.preventDefault/

http://api.jquery.com/event.stopPropagation/